# Inno Setup : Automatically check a checkbox after a specified time in seconds

Tags: checkbox, inno-setup

Hello I want My Inno Setup Script to automatically check a `CheckBox` in one of my wizard pages after a specified time (e.g. 5 seconds).

*Here's Why:*

*I created a checkbox which can change `WizardForm`'s `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight` when toggled.*

*If I don't click on it, the width and height of the `WizardForm` stays same. That's how it behaves.*

---

The code I written to do that:

```pascal
var
  MinimizerCheckBox: TNewCheckBox;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  MinimizerCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);

  with MinimizerCheckBox do
  begin
    Name := 'MinimizerCheckBox';
    Parent := WizardForm;
    Left := ScaleX(560);
    Top := ScaleY(315);
    Width := ScaleX(90);
    Height := ScaleY(14);
    Alignment := taLeftJustify;
    Caption := 'Compact Mode';
    OnClick := @MinimizerCheckBoxClick;
    TabOrder := 3;
  end;
end;

procedure MinimizerCheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if MinimixerCheckBox.Checked then
  begin
    with WizardForm do
    begin
      WizardForm.ClientWidth:=420;
      WizardForm.ClientHeight:=175;
    end;
  end else begin
    with WizardForm do
    begin
      WizardForm.ClientWidth:=654;
      WizardForm.ClientHeight:=407;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I want to check that checkbox automatically after a specified time.

*Any example code to do this?*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule a timer to check the checkbox like this:

```pascal
[Code]

var
  MinimizerCheckBox: TCheckBox;

...

function SetTimer(
  hWnd: longword; nIDEvent, uElapse: longword; lpTimerFunc: longword): longword;
  external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd: HWND; uIDEvent: UINT): BOOL; 
  external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall'; 

var
  CheckTimerID: Integer;

procedure StopCheckTimer;
begin
  Log('Killing timer');
  KillTimer(0, CheckTimerID);
  CheckTimerID := 0;
end;

procedure CheckProc(h: LongWord; msg: LongWord; idevent: LongWord; dwTime: LongWord);
begin
  Log('Timer elapsed');
  StopCheckTimer;
  MinimizerCheckBox.Checked := True;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpXXX then { your page id }
  begin
    Log('Starting 5s timer');
    CheckTimerID := SetTimer(0, 0, 5000, CreateCallback(@CheckProc));
  end
    else
  if CheckTimerID <> 0 then
  begin
    StopCheckTimer;
  end;
end;
```

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library.*